# RUSLE - LS - Factor

Tags: rusle

Regarding slope lenght, DESMET & GOVERS (1996) based:

[image]

the following equation used in the LS factor SAGA GIS module (URL: https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/code/ci/master/tree/saga-gis/src/tools/terrain_analysis/ta_hydrology/Erosion_LS_Fields.cpp#l497):

and the following C++ code:

```
L = (pow(Area + Get_Cellarea(), m + 1.0) - pow(Area, m + 1.0))
/ (pow(Get_Cellsize(), m + 2.0) * pow(22.13, m) * pow(x, m));
```

what is the meaning, in a grid or raster GIS file, of:
a) Area
b) Get_Cellarea
c) Get_Cellsize?

Comment: Deleting downvoted questions and reposting them can result in anti-spam mechanisms suspending your SE login. Instead, [Edit] the Question to address the issue (ALLCAPS title) and the downvote can be removed. Please take the [Tour] to better understand how GIS SE operates.

Comment: The question have ALL CAPS title and it's focused but still have a downvote scored by @Vince, not removed.

Comment: You haven't addressed the ALLCAPS title, and added an ALLCAPS to the question body. I can't vote to reopen that.

Comment: Missed that, not sure why needed. Thought was in the body.

Comment: Now there's *more* "shouting"  in the title, not less (ALLCAPS is *bad*, not a requirement).  It's a pain to correct case, so it's more likely just get downvoted, not corrected.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Regarding several documentation** (1):

1) Ajin = "flowaccumulation x area of a cell" [area (m2)]; 2) Ajin + D^2 = "flowaccumulation x area of a cell  + area of a cell" [Get_Cellarea (m2)] or [Get_Cellsize (m)].

(1) **REFERENCES:**

CONRAD, O., BETCHEL, B., BOCK, M., DIETRICH, H., FISCHER, E., GERTLITZ, L., WEHBERG, J., WICHMANN, V., and BOEHNER, J. (2015). System for Automated Geoscientific Analyses (SAGA) v. 2.1.4. Geosci. Model Dev., 8, 1991-2007, doi:10.5194/gmd-8-1991-2015.

DESMET, P. J. J.; GOVERS, G. A. (1996). GIS Procedure of automatically calculation the USLE LS factor on topographically complex landscape units. Journal of Soil and Water Conservation. v. 5, n. 5, p. 427­-433.

KINNELL, P.I.A. (2005). Alternative Approaches for Determining the USLE-M Slope Length Factor for Grid Cells. United States : Soil Science Society of America, Soil Science Society of America Journal, 69 , pp. 674-680.

MITASOVA H., Hofierka J., Zlocha M., Iverson L.R. (1996). Modelling topographic potential for erosion and deposition using GIS. International Journal of Geographical Information Systems, 10: 629-641.

OLSSON, Mikael (2013). C++ Quick Syntax Reference. Online: https://https://github.com/apress/c-plus-plus-quick-syntax-reference).

SILVA, V. C. (2007). Cálculo automático do fator topográfico (LS) DA EUPS, na bacia do rio Paracatu. Pesquisa Agropecuária Tropical (Agricultural Research in the Tropics), v. 33, n. 1, p. 29-34, 16 nov.

WISCHMEIER, W. H. & SMITH, D. D. (1978). Predicting rainfall erosion losses: a guide to conservation planning. U.S. Departament of Agriculture, Washington. 58 p. Agriculture Handbook 537.

WISCHMEIER, W. H., SMITH, D. D. (1965). Prediction Rainfall Erosion Losses from Cropland East of the Rocky Mountains: A Guide for Selection of Practices for Soil and Water Conservation. U.S. Department of Agriculture Handbook 282, Washington DC.

Comment: **Hi, you can see this.**
Regarding the circumstances, suggest closing, permanently, this particular, Q&A.
Best regards